# jQuery call function in script

Tags: jquery

I have written a simple jQuery function and try to call it. It just won't start. I'm new to jQuery and I can't find the mistake which I make.

**Here my Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        // Function goes here
        function myFunction(inputArray)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++)
                {
                    alert(inputArray[i]);
                }
        }

        // Start of the function goes here
        var array = new Array("This", "Is", "JQuery");

        $(function(){
            myFunction(array);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `int`?! Java isn't JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

Use [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) not *int*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    // Function goes here
    function myFunction(inputArray) {
      for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        alert(inputArray[i]);
      }
    }

    // Start of the function goes here
    var array = new Array("This", "Is", "JQuery");

    $(function() {
      myFunction(array);
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can change to alerts, better use console.log